# LINQ group by day of the week throwing exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, group-by

I'm trying to group my data by the day of the week and then sum the sales like this:

```
ViewBag.DailyGraph = ctx.StoreItemTransactions
                        .GroupBy(x => x.TransactionDate.Value.DayOfWeek)
                        .Select(pr => new { Day = pr.Key, 
                                            Sales = pr.Sum(x => x.QuantitySoldTransaction) 
                               })
                        .ToDictionary(y => y.Day, y => y.Sales);
```

But I'm getting this exception:

> The specified type member 'DayOfWeek' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

How can I workaround this ? I'm basically trying to group all my data by 7 days in week so that output would be:

```
Monday    1  
Tuesday   5
...
Sunday   14
```

Can someone help me out with this?

@StephenMuecke, by applying what you told me  I was able to finish the code and sort all days as they should:

```
var DailyGraph = ctx.StoreItemTransactions.ToList()
                    .GroupBy(x => x.TransactionDate.Value.DayOfWeek)
                    .Select(pr => new HourlyGraph
                                  { Day = pr.Key.ToString(),
                                    Sales = pr.Sum(x => x.QuantitySoldTransaction) 
                           });

 var dayIndex = new List<string> { "MONDAY", "TUESDAY", "WEDNESDAY", "THURSDAY", "FRIDAY", "SATURDAY", "SUNDAY" };
 ViewBag.DailyGraph = DailyGraph.OrderBy(e => dayIndex.IndexOf(e.Day.ToUpper())).ToList();
```

Maybe there's a better way to solve this, I will wait for ur answer as well =)

Comment: You can materialize the query fiirst - `StoreItemTransactions.ToList().GroupBy(....`

Comment: Which type of variable is DayOfWeek?

Comment: @Tinwor it is the enumerable DayOfWeek

Comment: @StephenMuecke thx yeah that works like a charm. Quick question mate, what's the best way now to sort all days, due to the fact that they are in string form, I guess I can't just say: .OrderBy(x=>x.Day) => this "shouldn't" do anything since this is string ? =D

Comment: Its an `enum` so you can cast it to an `int` (e.g. `(int)Day`) but you using a dictionary so sorting does not really make sense - you will probably want a view model with properties `DayOfWeek Day` and `int Sales` and project the query into a collection of that model

Comment: @StephenMuecke Good point. It's odd actually, u can see i'm creating an anonymous object up there in code when performing select, when I try to do foreach loop in the view it tells me it can't find the definition for the properties of the anonymous object by saying: "object does not contain definition for "Day"'

Comment: @StephenMuecke take your time mate, thanks a lot =) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you also want to order the results by `DayOfWeek`, using a `Dictionary` is not appropriate, and you should start with a view model to represent what you want in the view

```
public class SalesVM
{
    public DayOfWeek Day { get; set; }
    public int Sales { get; set; }
}
```

In order to prevent the exception, materialize your query first (using `ToList()` or `.AsEnumerable()`) and I suggest you just satrt by selecting only the data you need from the database

```
ViewBag.DailyGraph = ctx.StoreItemTransactions
    .Select(x => new { Date = x.Date, Sales = x.Sales }) // select only required data
    .ToList() // materialize
    .GroupBy(x => x.Date.DayOfWeek) // group by day of week
    .Select(x => new TestVM() { Day = x.Key, Sales = x.Sum(y => y.Sales) }) // project to view model
    .OrderBy(x => (int)x.Day); // order by day of week
```

Answer (score 2):

Linq to Entities does not know how to tranlsate that property of DateTime to sql, you need to use [**SqlFunctions.DatePart**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.datepart(v=vs.110).aspx) method for getting the dayofweek in the groupby which can be done following way :

```
var result = ctx.StoreItemTransactions
                .GroupBy(x => SqlFunctions.DatePart("weekday", x.TransactionDate))
                .Select(pr => new HourlyGraph
                        { 
                           Day = pr.Key.ToString(),
                           Sales = pr.Sum(x => x.QuantitySoldTransaction) 
                       });
```